# Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins on EC2 Suse Linux and have a Jenkins job which gives me following error:

```
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sampleMulti_develop/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I verified `JAVA_HOME` by which java shows: `/usr/bin/java`, gave same path in global tool configuration. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have only the **Java Runtime Environment installed (JRE)**.

For running Jenkins, you need the **Java Development Kit (JDK)** which contains the `javac` binary for compiling Java code.

I am no expert in SuSe but I think you can install Open JDK using [this link](https://software.opensuse.org/package/java-1_8_0-openjdk).

Comment: javac binary was missing in my JDK